# Terse finite state machines in Haskell

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming, haskell, finite-state-machine

I'm writing a parser for a markup language in haskell, and a finite state machine fell out of my ideal API. I have code that looks a bit like this:

```hs
Token = BoldWord String | Word String | ParagraphBreak | HorizontalRule -- etc, etc
State = Accept Token State
      | LineStart
      | ParagraphStart
      | WordStart
      | BuildingWord String
        -- etc, etc
```

The complete enumeration of states gets quite long quite quickly, and, what's more, I have only three functions to deal with it all:

```hs
parse = parseInner ParagraphStart
parseInner _ "" = ""
parseInner s x  =
  case performState s $ head x of
       Accept t s -> show t ++ parseInner s (tail x)
       nc -> parseInner nc (tail x)

performState :: State -> Char -> State
-- (ommiting the implementation)
```

This works, but performState gets *long* (80-ish lines after pruning for a very small subset of my target input language), and I've barely begun the parser. Are there other terser patterns for finite state machines in Haskell?

Comment: I am a bit confused where your concern is.  Are you concerned on the definitions for each type of Token?  Or are you concerned about your implementation needing to cover every case for every type of Token?  If the former you might be able to make this more clear with the syntax sugar for data objects.  The latter then you might be able to write a general parseInner function that operates on Typeclasses.

Comment: @maple_shaft My concern is less about each Token variant needing to be handled individually and more about each State variant needing to be handled individually in performState - there's just too many variants to handle in a reasonably sized func. Could you say more about using typeclasses?

Comment: Hard to say because it isn't completely clear about what a State is, but a Typeclass is like a contract that ensures a particular function will be defined for a Type Eg. Eq for equality, Ord for ordererable, etc....  If your function on State say only has to ensure something is equatable to something else, or has to be shown, then your function can be defined to take any instance of the Typeclass as opposed to the Type directly.

Comment: Another thing you can consider is that this is a sign that performState is just too general or too big.  You could also create more specific functions that wrap Tokens and give them a parent type so to speak, then you can pass these to smaller functions that are easier to test and reason about.

Comment: A long function isn't bad by itself if it is organized and understandable.  And it is completely expected in a state machine.  If you're unhappy with the number of states: well, design a simpler state machine (if you can, for your problem).  The classic way of handling state machines, by the way, is to _generate code_ (or tables) from a more expressive yet simpler notation, typically, some sort of diagram.  Consider a translator from such a notation (e.g., [plantuml's](https://plantuml.com/state-diagram)) to a table/datastructure or to a haskell function.